The method 'LatLng' isn't defined/ The method 'LatLngBounds' isn't defined
I developed a pretty good working app (where I had database and google map). Today, I noticed that I was getting some errors especially in Map (Error when passing latitude and longitude to Latlng)- I haven't done any change.
Can it be related to email about Maps "Apps built with the Maps SDK for Android will be automatically updated to the latest renderer starting March 4, 2024."
I renewed the API key from the Google console, cleared the flutter caches and reinstalled it all, but it doesn't work.
Flutter 2.8.1 (it must be in this version).
Dart 2.15.1
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.12
I renewed the API key from the Google console, cleared the flutter caches and reinstalled it all, but it doesn't work.

minSdkVersion is 21.

You can upgrade Your google maps to 2.7.0 ,
replace your pubscpec.yaml :
google_maps_flutter: ^2.7.0

in the update google solved this error on the newer phones
